# Changing Bindng Of WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, binding

I have a WCF service which is hosted in a windows service. For testing, I just kept the default http binding and it is now working fine. However, I want to use the tcp binding. I right clicked on app.config and Edit WCF Configuration. From the editor, I changed the endpoint bindings to netTcpBinding and mexTcpBinding. I also changed the Host BaseAddress to net.tcp://localhost:9100

However, now when I install and start the windows service it stops imemdiately.

What have I done wrong or not done?

Comment: Have you looked in your Windows Application Event Log?

Comment: What you did wrong? You didn't implement logging ...

Comment: add your configuration code, it will make easy for people to figure out.

Comment: I had left httpGetEnabled set to true. Set it to false and it now works.

Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting debugger "ON" by using the below code in config and check the log for error details. Please share the error message written in log that will help us to identify root cause of the problem.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog"  />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```